# How to name final List variable in java?

Tags: java, coding-style, sun-coding-conventions

Should I name a final List as

```
private final List<MaleSwimmer> MALE_SWIMMER_LIST=new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
private final List<MaleSwimmer> maleSwimmerList=new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
private final List<MaleSwimmer> maleSwimmers=new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
private final List<MaleSwimmer> MALESWIMMERS=new ArrayList<>();
```

What is the best coding convention?

Comment: You should use either `maleSwimmerList` or `maleSwimmers` as it's not a constant.

Comment: Convention is to use camelCase

Answer (score 1):

I would rather prefer `maleSwimmers` as it is simple and it states what is that. It is not necessary to put `List` in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 or 3 I guess, but all of them are OK for the compiler. Note that when you instantiate, use the containing object